# Посчитать количество прожитых дней на с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пользователь вводит дату своего рождения и текущую дату. Посчитать количество прожитых дней.
Где ошибка?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int day1, month1, year1, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, count = 0;
    int day2, month2, year2;
    int mon[12] = {31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    cout << "Введите дату рождения: ";
    cin >> day1 >> "." >> month1 >> "." >> year1;
    cout << "Введите дату сегоднешнего дня: ";
    cin >> day2 >> "." >> month2 >> "." >> year2;

    //////////////////////ПЕРВАЯ ЧАСТЬ
    for (int i = 0; i < (year1 - 1); i++)
    {
        if (i % 4 != 0)
        {
            sum1 += 365;
        }
        else
        {
            sum1 += 366;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < (month1 - 1); j++)
    {
        sum1 += mon[j];
    }

    if (year1 % 4 != 0)
    {
        sum1 += day1;
    }
    else if ((year1 % 4 == 0) && (month1 > 2))
    {
        sum1 += (day1 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        sum1 += day1;
    }

    ////////////////////ВТОРАЯ ЧАСТЬ
    for (int i = 0; i < (year2 - 1); i++)
    {
        if (i % 4 != 0)
        {
            sum2 += 365;
        }
        else
        {
            sum2 += 366;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < (month2 - 1); j++)
    {
        sum2 += mon[j];
    }

    if (year2 % 4 != 0)
    {
        sum2 += day2;
    }
    else if ((year2 % 4 == 0) && (month2 > 2))
    {
        sum2 += (day2 + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        sum2 += day2;
    }

    ///////////////////ВЫВОД
    cout << "Количество прожитых дней: " << sum2 - sum1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем собственно выражается ошибка?

Comment: Она просто не запускается

Comment: А ошибка какая?

Comment: ""C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\Laba3\Debug\A7.exe"" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Значительно проще, используя функцию [mktime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246472(v=vs.60).aspx) (или можно почитать `man 3 mktime`) получить даты **в секундах**. Затем просто делите разность в секундах на  длительность дня в них ( `24 * 60 * 60` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Она у вас просто НЕ КОМПИЛИРУЕТСЯ, вот нечему и запускаться!

Как вы себе представляете этот пассаж:

```
cin >> day1 >> "." >> month1 >> "." >> year1;
```

Что значит ввести в литерал `"."`?

Нет программы - нечего и запускать...

Работайте над текстом.

P.S. Рекомендую, кстати, посмотреть в сторону [модифицированной юлианской даты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) - программа сразу резко упростится...

P.P.S. Кстати, оно-то в пределах XX и XXI веков не сыграет, но учтите, что не все годы, которые делятся на 4 - високосные...

Comment: Ок, а как тогда вывести дату через точки?

Comment: Вывести или ввести? `cin>>` - это ввод данных... Вывести, например, так: `cout << day << "." << month << "." << year;`. Конечно, лучше выводить с ведущими нулями для однозначных чисел, но для начала просто запустите программу...

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, оттого что в феврале 28/29 дней, а в приведённом коде — тридцать.

**UPD**:

```
int mon[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
cout << "Введите дату рождения: ";
cin >> day1;
cin >> month1;
cin >> year1;
cout << "Введите дату сегоднешнего дня: ";
cin >> day2;
cin >> month2;
cin >> year2;
//////////////////////ПЕРВАЯ ЧАСТЬ
```

Comment: все равно не работает, она даже не запускается

Comment: Попробуйте так (см. выше). Дату только нужно будет вводить не через точку, а через пробел.